# If else React TypeScript - bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, use-state, react-typescript

I have new message button and few conversations. When I click on the conversation, the right side should show message box and when I click on the new message, should show the create new message box.
Here is my useState and handlers:

```
const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState<string>('');
    const [conversations, setConversationsState] = useState<string>('');

    const newMessageHandler = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const button: HTMLButtonElement = event.currentTarget;
    setNewMessage(button.id);
  

    };
  const conversationsHandler = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const div: HTMLDivElement = event.currentTarget;
    setConversationsState(div.id);
  };
```

Here is my if else jsx:

```
{
     (() => {
      if (newMessage)
      return <NewMessageComponent />

      else if (conversations)
         return (
          <>
            {tempData.map(
              (tempdata) =>
                conversations === tempdata.id && (
                  <MessageBox
                    name={tempdata.name}
                  />
                ),
            )}
          </>
        )
      else 
         return <span>No Conversations Selected</span>
  })()

}
```

For one time, conversation and new message appears well when onClick. But then conversation is not showing after clicking new message.

Please help! Thanks in advance

### Update:

I changed state and handler like this

```
const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [conversations, setConversationsState] = useState<string>('');

const newMessageHandler = () => {
    setNewMessage(true);
  };
const conversationsHandler = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const div: HTMLDivElement = event.currentTarget;
    setConversationsState(div.id);
    setNewMessage(false);
  };
```

and my if- else like this

```
(() => {
          if (newMessage)
          return <NewMessageComponent />

          else 
             return (conversations?
              <>
                {tempData.map(
                  (tempdata) =>
                    conversations === tempdata.id && (
                      <MessageBox
                        name={tempdata.name}
                      />
                    ),
                )}
              </> :
              <span>No conversations selected</span>
            )
         
      })()
```

If anyone need to refer, this worked well for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that you get proper data in `newMessage` and `conversations`.

If you are getting that then try this snippet for the JSX:

```
{ newMessage &&  <NewMessageComponent /> }
{ conversations &&  <MessageBox/> /> }
{ (!newMessage && !conversations)  && <span>No Conversations Selected</span> }
```